# Resolve hostname by my own

Tags: tcp, dns

How can I resolve the hostname of a specific device based on it's IP address?

I know that this has something to do with `DNS`, but my question is: What do I have to do to do this job by my own? Do I have to assemble a DNS packet or is there a different way?

I'm asking this question, since the .NET API throws an exception when resovling a IP to it's hostnamen if the hostname is not recorded.

Answer (score 0):

There are special reverse domains, e.g. for IPv4 it looks like this:

`$ dig -x 172.217.23.238
;...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
238.23.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN   PTR     prg03s06-in-f14.1e100.net.
238.23.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN   PTR     prg03s06-in-f238.1e100.net.
;...`